# Copyright for a thesis

Tags: thesis, copyright

In my thesis most illustrations are mine but some of them aren't and all the illustrations that aren't mine are used with permission.

However, my college department has a history of plagiarism. What would be a proper way of writing "unless stated otherwise, every illustration is mine" and "all credited illustrations are used with the explicit owner's permission" on the copyright page?

I didn't sign anything to give the rights and in my country by default I am the legal owner of the work so it would just be a way to make sure they can't say that they didn't know it was protected.

Answer (score 1):

You can just copyright your whole thesis, unless of course, your institution acquires it as a condition of your degree. The latter would be very rare in the US. By just putting in the phrase copyright 2023 Dunno somewhere on the title page you prevent anyone from claiming that they thought it was free.

The problem is more what to do if someone "steals" your illustrations etc. You need to be harmed in order to demand being made good.

Comment: Thank you. But would it mean that every not-credited illustration would be made by me?